# How to make primefaces chartJS responsive when window resized?

Tags: primefaces, chart.js, resize, responsive

How to make primefaces chartJS responsive when window resized?

Which client api method for resizing canvas?

Comment: See this example the charts are responsive to browser size: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml  You just need to to give it height and width to its container its automatically responsive.

Comment: The code is the same as the showcase example. The generated html markup: 

<div id="barchart" class="ui-chart"><canvas id="barchart_canvas" style="width:100%;height:300px"></canvas></div>

Comment: Does the PF showcase use any resize listener to update the canvas? or it happens by chartJS itself?

Comment: The chart width is responsive when window resizes bigger, but is not when window resizes smaller.

Comment: it is for me in that Showcase example the chart is resizing when the browser gets bigger or smaller?

Comment: actually size is specified in the canvas, not in the container with class ui-chart.